# Convert PST date millis to UTC millis

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, utc, java-time

In a data stream, I'm receiving date attribute values in milliseconds in Pacific timezone. Like for date = `Wed Jan 18 2023 18:00:00` Pacific Time, I'm receiving milliseconds value as `1674064800000`. It is milliseconds since 1/1/1970 0:00 PST (I am 100 % sure).

But I want to store this in UTC. How can `1674064800000` millis in PST be converted to `1674093600000` millis in UTC in java/kotlin?

Comment: Do you need to do this ? Are your millis not since 1/1/1970 UTC, regardless of the timezone your date/time is displayed at ? e.g. see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#millis--

Comment: First don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. It’s a notorious troublemaker of a class. Use java.time. Said because you tagged your question simpledateformat.

Comment: Yes, need to do this. No, the millis are since 1/1/1970 PST. I want to convert them to  millis since 1/1/1970 UTC.

Comment: PST millis and UTC millis are the same. It seems you misunderstood. @BrianAgnew is right.

Comment: yes, @user16320675

Comment: *No, the millis are since 1/1/1970 PST.* No kidding? You are 100 % sure? That’s extremely non-standard. If it’s true, then probably because somebody misunderstood the concept of epoch millis at a point in the history of your software.

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% sure. Pacific Standard Time.

Comment: `ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.EPOCH, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")).plus(1674064800000L, ChronoUnit.MILLIS).toInstant().toEpochMilli()` yields the desired 1674093600000. Declare `ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.EPOCH, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))` as a constant, though. (Or the hack: simply add the 28800000 milliseconds to the original value.)

Comment: `PST` is not a real time zone. `PST` might mean *Pacific Standard Time*, or it might mean *Pitcairn Standard Time*. If it means *Pacific Standard Time*, that pseudo zone implies any number of real time zones such as `America/Los_Angeles`, `America/Vancouver`, `America/Tijuana`, etc. These various real time zones may have different results depending on how far into the future or past you are projecting from 1970. Your Question is quite confusing, and ultimately unanswerable.

Comment: I was surprised to see this question closed as needing details or clarity. In my opinion what is unclear is not the question itself, it’s clear. It’s the OP’s comment under the answer that millis = `1655575200000L` should be `Sat Jun 18 2022 18:00:00 UTC`, the relevancy of which is questionable since the mentioned amount of milliseconds after 1/1/1970 0:00 Pacific Time is 2022-06-18T19:00-07:00[America/Vancouver]. Because of summer time/DST it’s 19:00, not 18:00.

Answer (score 3):

It's a very strange need, as time since 1970-01-01 is usually epoch-time, which is time zone independant.
However, you can achieve your need by adding your offset to a set time, like this:

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.EPOCH.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("America/Vancouver")).toInstant().toEpochMilli() + millis)
```

Comment: `atStartOfDay(ZoneId)` could be used too

Comment: Thanks. I edited my response to comply with your comments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This will convert millis = `1655575200000L, Sat Jun 18 2022 18:00:00 UTC` to `1655604000000L, Sun Jun 19 2022 02:00:00 UTC`. But it should be `1655600400000L, Sun Jun 19 2022 01:00:00 UTC` considering daylight savings time.

Comment: @sahillearner Same question again: Are you 100 % sure? It does not make sense. UTC does not have summer time (DST). And Pacific Time was not in summer on January 1 1970. So we should be able to leave summer time completely out of the math.